# Php how i can create subfolders?

Tags: php

I want to create sub folders , but I want to make is that if the higher levels do not exist create them .
There is a php function that allows to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
mkdir(/upload_dir/new_file_name, 0777, true);
```

may be helpfull

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can use `mkdir()` by setting the `recursive` parameter to true.

From the [documention for mkdir() on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php):

```
bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )
```

So you would want to do something like this:

```
// The true is the important part.
mkdir('/path/to/directory', 755, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the third parameter of [mkdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) to true and you can create nested directories.

> **recursive**
>
> Allows the creation of nested directories specified in the pathname.

For example you want to create the folder "test" inside of two other folders:

```
mkdir('/folder_1/folder_2/test', 0777, true);
```